# Multi-line control in VCL forms

Tags: c++, vcl, trichedit

I am using C++ Builder to create a VCL forms application and am wanting a multiline editbox.

Am I correct in saying that I have to use a TRichEdit control to accomplish this?

If so, (and I have added one just to try out), how do I set the text in the control? There seems to be no .text or .caption property.

I can get the contents of the TRichEdit by the ->text property, but how do I 'set' the text?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Text` property is read/write:

```
String s = RichEdit1->Text;

RichEdit1->Text = ...;
```

It is just declared as `__published` so you will not see it in the Object Inspector at design time.  If you want to see the text at design time, you have to use the `Lines` property instead.

BTW, `TRichEdit` is not the only multi-line edit control.  `TMemo` is another one.  The main difference between them is that `TRichEdit` supports more formatting options than `TMemo` does.  Think of them as the VCL equivalents of the MSWord and Notepad apps, respectively.